# How to convert from a string to a Flags enum format in C#

Tags: c#, enums, type-conversion, enum-flags

I have this enum:

```
[Flags]
public enum Countries
{
    None    = 0,
    USA     = 1,
    Mexico  = 2,
    Canada  = 4,
    Brazil  = 8,
    Chile   = 16
}
```

I receive in input strings like these:

```
string selectedCountries = "Usa, Brazil, Chile";
```

how to convert it (in C#) back to:

```
var myCountries = Countries.Usa | Countries.Brazil | Countries.Chile;
```

Comment: Can you fix the string initialization?

Comment: Nope I can't, I just receive strings formatted like that which is the default way flags enum are saved into strings.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `string selectedCountries = "Usa, Brazil, Chile";`?

Comment: You are correct Maor, my mistake, I will edit the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [Enum.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559(v=vs.110).aspx).

e.g. `Countries c = (Countries)Enum.Parse(typeof(Countries), "Usa, Brazil...");`

Comment: I agree it should Enum.Parse but don't think you can pass in the whole string directly into Enum.Parse.

Comment: Yes you can I just tested it.
You are actually converting that string into a number and then casting it to enum. 
Thanks Tyranid

Comment: @Paul_T are you saing you can pass the string `Usa, Brazil` directly into `Enum.Parse` and it works?

Comment: That's correct stt106: if you pass the string "Usa, Brazil, Chile" to the Enum.parse it will work.
After this call
Countries c = (Countries)Enum.Parse(typeof(Countries), "Usa, Brazil..."); c stores Countries.Usa | Countries.Brazil | Countries.Chile

Comment: If you want to avoid possible exception use Enum.TryParse<Countries>("Usa, Brazil", out Countries c)

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work for me assuming your country string is separated by a comma:

```
private static Countries ConvertToCountryEnum(string country)
        {
            return country.Split(',').Aggregate(Countries.None, (seed, c) => (Countries)Enum.Parse(typeof(Countries), c, true) | seed);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I realized that it is easier than what i thought.
All I need to do is convert that string into an int, in my case, or a long in general, and cast it to Countries.
It will convert that number into the expected format.
In other words:

```
(Countries) 25 = Countries.Usa | Countries.Brazil | Countries.Chile;
```

Comment: That doesn't seem valid C#.

Comment: Ok Patrick  what I meant is that casting an int with an enum equals the "or" of the bits. Usa + Brazil + Chile = 1 +8 +16 = 25 not as C# code though.